# How to add error message alertbox in the given code?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function gcd()
{
var x,y;
x=parseInt(document.myform.n1.value);
y=parseInt(document.myform.n2.value);
if((x>'a' && x<='z') && (y>'a' && y<='z') && (x>'A' && x<='Z') && (y>'A' && y<='Z'))
{
while(x!=y)
{                           
    if(x>y)
        x=x-y;
    else
        y=y-x;
}
document.myform.result.value=x;
}
else
{
    alert("Enter valid character ! ");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center"><b>gcd of two numbers</b></h1>
<hr color="black">
<center>
Enter two numbers :
<form name="myform">
Number 1 : <input type="text" name="n1" value=""> <br> <br>
Number 2 : <input type="text" name="n2" value=""> <br> <br>
<input type="button" value="Get GCD" onClick="gcd()"> <br> <br>
GCD is : <input type="text" name="result" value="">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is an HTML-javascript code but I am trying to add a feature which would pop up an alert box if you enter a special character.Please help me figure out why the above code is not working .I'm a beginner at javascript and need your help.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried doing Regex ( Regular Expression) ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want some `||` in that expression. A character can never be both lower- and uppercase.

Comment: @BanelingRush Regex is a bit over-engineered here, and probably testing the character is not the problem the OP faces.

Comment: @Bergi yes over-engineered maybe... but considering he wants to check for certain characters a regex check with an alert toast is probably the shortest way to do so

Comment: Ya but I'm a beginner in javascript I don't know regular expression and want this done

Answer (score 0):

The best way to not only handle errors but make sure that the text is in the desired format would be to use [Regular Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp). Basic validation here could be done as said below by setting input type to number, although is not recommended.

You can always handle errors by [Javascript Error Handling](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp).

Would recommend doing more research on the following for your use case and figure out what your ideal case would be. Hope this helps !

Comment: Can you sugest me a small tweak in my original code that would get my purpose solved

Comment: Change your if statement to be this - `if(((x>'a' && x<='z') || (x>'A' && x<='Z')) && ((y>'a' && x<='z') || (y>'A' && y<='Z')))` should work although its a hacky way to get around this. Although i dont understand why you would allow character inputs like this as said above setting the type to number is a more efficient way to convert since you want numerical values

Answer (score 0):

Simply do with Change the input type with `number` .Its only allow the number

```js
function gcd() {
  var x, y;
  x = document.myform.n1.value;
  y = document.myform.n2.value
  x = parseInt(x);
  y = parseInt(y)
  if (x > y) {
    x = x - y;
  } else {
    x = y - x;
  }
  document.myform.result.value = x;
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center"><b>gcd of two numbers</b></h1>
<hr color="black">
<center>
  Enter two numbers :
  <form name="myform">
    Number 1 : <input type="number" name="n1" value=""> <br> <br> Number 2 : <input type="number" name="n2" value=""> <br> <br>
    <input type="button" value="Get GCD" onClick="gcd()"> <br> <br> GCD is : <input type="number" name="result" value="">
  </form>
```